# Icon from a .lnk file to javafx Image

Tags: java, javafx, bufferedimage

I'm am trying to get the Icon from a .lnk file, put it into a javafx Image and then save it as a .png file (to ensure it's working).

My current code compiles but does not work:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
class Iconic {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        File origin = new File("C:\\Users\\00001\\OneDrive.lnk");
        Icon icn = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(origin);
        ImageIcon ico = ((ImageIcon) icn);
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
            ico.getIconWidth(),
            ico.getIconHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();
        ico.paintIcon(null,g,0,0);
        g.dispose();
        Image img = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bi,null);

        File output = new File("C:\\Users\\00001\\");
        BufferedImage bim = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(img,null);
        ImageIO.write(bim,".png",output);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Does not work". So what happens? Do you get an exception? If so, post the stack trace. And it looks like you are trying to write the image to a directory at the end...?

Comment: Currently, it does not throw any exceptions, however it does not save the .lnk file's icon as a .jpg

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, however, there are two issues in your code. Both are related to the `ImageIO.write(...)` method.

From the API doc of [`ImageIO.write(RenderedImage, String, File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write(java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)):

> Writes an image using an arbitrary `ImageWriter` that supports the given format to a `File`. If there is already a `File` present, its contents are discarded.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> `im` - a `RenderedImage` to be written.
>
> `formatName` - a `String` containg the informal name of the format.
>
> `output` - a `File` to be written to.

1. The second parameter is *the format name*, not the file extension. So, the second argument should be "PNG", not ".png". Because `ImageIO` does not find any plugins that can write ".png" format, the `write(...)` invocation will just silently return `false`. I recommend always checking the return value of `ImageIO.write(...)`.
2. The third parameter is the *destination file* to write. The path of this file has to point to a file, however yours point only to a directory. If you fix only the format name above, you'll see that most likely you get an `IOException`.

So, a fixed version of your writing code would like like:

```
File output = new File(origin.getParentFile(), origin.getName().replace(".lnk", ".png"));

if (!ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", output)) {
    System.err.println("Could not write icon");
}
```

I deliberately left the conversion from FX `Image` out. You should be able to write `bi` directly, without conversion to and from FX `Image`(unless, of course, you manipulate the image in FX).